# $1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{p-1}$ in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

In $\mathbb{Q}$, $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}$ is always irreducible by Eisenstein criterion.

What is an example of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, and a prime $p$ such that $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first examples that come to mind are:

- $p=7$, $q=2$. Modulo $2$ we have
  $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^3).$$
- $p=3$, $q=7$. Modulo $7$ we have
  $$1+x+x^2=(x-2)(x-4).$$

Earlier today I explained [how to figure out when a cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ is irreducible over a prime field $\Bbb{F}_q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609923/11619). This is a special case of that general result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: nice answer +1 @Jyrki Lahtonen

Answer (score 3):

For $q=p=3$, consider $1+x+x^2=(x+2)^2$. Hence reducible.

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks.